# Indesign Grep function to break email addresses on @ symbol

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles, grep, data-merge

I'm trying to fit email addresses in a staff directory and wish to have the emails break on @ in order to have them look more consistent. I'm importing the email addresses via a data merge as well which may complicate matters.

Example of what I want:
John.Doe
@email.com

I've tried adding a paragraph style with the following Grep function but no luck:

<S+@S+>

[image: An image where the email is broken after the @ symbol]

[image: An image where the email is broken at the @ symbol]

Comment: Show an example of what you want to achieve. What do you mean by "break"? Edit your question and post a picture.

Comment: This has been done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is technical and may or not work with your particular setup, but you can try this **after the data merge stage**.

Find this :

- `@(\w+\.[\l\u]{3})`

And replace with this :

- `\n@$1`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Lucian is great.

I am not sure what you exactly would like to achieve, but if you want to keep the `@` in place and move all that follows to the lower line (just as in your screenshot), you may precede `\n` by the `@` sign in the "Change to" field:

Find What: `@(\w+\.[\w]{2,3})`

Change to: `@\n$1`

Or:

Find What: `\w+@\K(\w+\.[\w]{2,3})`

Change to: `\n$1`

Otherwise please accept the answer of Lucian if it is satisfactory to you or provide some feedback. Thank you.